# Using WixIIsExtension and localization variable errors on building localized installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

When using the WixIIsExtension for WiX MSI project, for building localized installer (ru-RU culture, for example), I got a lot of such errors:

- the localization variable (loc.configureiis) is unknown. please ensure the variable is defined

I have the workaround for it - installing IIS application is organized as separate merge module without localizations. When I build WiX MergeModule project with using WixIIsExtension - it's OK.

But what is the reason of errors inside MSI project? Would it be fixed in later versions of WiX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS extension messages are not localized into russian. You can just specify a "fallback" culture, so that existing (English) messages are used. In the project settings, set "ru-RU,en-US" in the "Cultures to build", instead of just "ru-RU".

See more about fallback cultures: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/specifying_cultures_to_build.html

These non-localized strings of the iis extension are just shown for a fraction of a second when progress bar runs, and in the log files.

Anyways, you could also provide the translations yourself (or wait until they are provided :) To translate yourself, you could download the wix source code (wix39-debug.zip), then copy the file named `wix39-debug\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\en-us.wxl` into your project (as ru-RU.wxl), include it in project, and then translate English strings.

Comment: Specifying a 'fallback' culture doesn't help. Before I encountered with this issue, I didn't specified cultures to build in project settings - as VS automatically builds installer for cultures specified in localization files. After this issue and your advice, I set up cultures to build (ru-RU;en-US). Still the same errors.

Comment: Separate fallback ultures with coma "," not semicolon ";" it has differerent meaning. RTFM.