# Cannot find ja-JP.wxl error message in IIsExtension source wix3-wix3111rtm

Tags: wix, wix3.11

Environment:Windows 10, Wix3.11.1, Visual Studio 2017 Community.

I want to find a way how to Light my wix object without several ja-JP localization messages in wixIISextension. I have found the right message in en-us.wxl in the 3.11.1 source code. But not in ja-JP.wxl.

Below is the light cmd which my VS 2017 creates.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\Light.exe -out D:\{hoge}\{hoge}.msi -pdbout D:\{hoge}\hoge.wixpdb -cultures:ja-JP -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\\WixIIsExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\\WixUtilExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\\WixUIExtension.dll" -contentsfile obj\Debug\{hoge}.wixproj.BindContentsFileListja-JP.txt -outputsfile obj\Debug\{hoge}.wixproj.BindOutputsFileListja-JP.txt -builtoutputsfile obj\Debug\{hoge}.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListja-JP.txt -wixprojectfile D:\{hoge\hoge}.wixproj obj\Debug\ConditionDlg.wixobj obj\Debug\Product.wixobj obj\Debug\ProductApplicationFiles.wixobj obj\Debug\ProductSettingFiles.wixobj
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension_Platform.wxi(12,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.ConfigureIIsExec) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension_Platform.wxi(18,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.ConfigureIIs7Exec) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension_Platform.wxi(19,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.StartIIS7ConfigTransaction) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension_Platform.wxi(20,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.RollbackIIS7ConfigTransaction) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension_Platform.wxi(21,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.CommitIIS7ConfigTransaction) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension_Platform.wxi(22,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.WriteIIS7ConfigChanges) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
> 2>C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\IIsExtension.wxs(56,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.msierrIISFailedCommitInUse) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.

When I downloaded the source code from the GitHub(https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3111rtm), I think I found the reason why I cannot light the code with IIsExtension (which making ApplicationPool in local IIS) In \src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib, I found a message "msierrIISFailedCommitInUse" in en-us.wxl, but not in ja-JP.wxl.

```
  <Component Id="cmpAppPool" Guid="MY-GUID" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="TestPool" Name="Test" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" Identity="networkService"  />
  </Component>
```

If my assumption is right, probably I should somehow try to replace the message list of Wix toolset installed in my local computer...But how? Any other ideas?

It might be wise to try to light my project in en-US language temporarily, but the project contains many japanese name files....

P.S.1
I have tried to set several cultures (reading http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/specifying_cultures_to_build.html), but the error continues.
[image]

Comment: I made a similar project without any japanese characters, with en-us, and found light generated msi without the error...

Comment: Reading Mr. Andrey G.A's old post(Wix3.9): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720115/using-wixiisextension-and-localization-variable-errors-on-building-localized-ins?rq=1, I have tried both 1)setting fallback culture (ja-JP, en-US) and 2)copying the file named src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\en-us.wxl into my project (as ja-JP.wxl), include it in project. Neither of them works.

Comment: I have posted this question to Wix mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer.

I have tried 2) copying the file named src\ext\IIsExtension\wixlib\en-us.wxl into my project (as ja-JP.wxl), include it in project. But failed to change its header Culture.

After I changed the header Culture from en-US to ja-JP, Light command works fine.

I am not sure why 1) didn't work.
Thank you for your concern.